# System.Text.Json - The JSON value could not be converted to System.String

Tags: json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have the following `json` being sent to api

```
{
     "Id":22,
     "UserId":22,
     "Payload":{
        "Field":"some payload value"
        ...more unknown field/values go here
     },
     "ContextTypeId":1,
     "EventTypeId":1,
     "SessionId":1
}
```

I would like to map it to the following:

```
  public class CreateTrackItem : IRequest<int>
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Payload { get; set; }
        public int ContextTypeId { get; set; }
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public int EventTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

When mapped the `Payload` property fails that it cannot map `json` to string, i simply want the `Payload` to be a `string` version of the `json` (will go into a `jsonb` field in `postgres`)

I am using .NET Core 3.0 and prefer to use the built in `System.Text.Json` if possible before switching to `Newtonsoft`.

Comment: `Payload` needs to be a `class` object with `property` `Field`. `"Payload":{
        "Field":"some payload value"     },` This is a complex object, not a string.

Comment: @RyanWilson since the payload structure is unknown, other than that it will be valid json, its impossible to construct a class, that is why the property is set to be a string which will take what ever json is thrown at it

Comment: Then you either need to write a custom `JSON Converter` or try using type `JToken`, please see this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980580/deserialize-json-object-property-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object type instead of string. Or use JToken type from Newtonsoft as Ryan already commented above.

> public object Payload { get; set; }

```
 public class CreateTrackItem : IRequest<int>
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public object Payload { get; set; }
    public int ContextTypeId { get; set; }
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    public int EventTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using asp.net core 3.0 (or `System.Text.Json` with .Net 6) then this has built-in JSON support. I have used the following and it works without setting the custom input handler.

```
//// using System.Text.Json;

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] JsonElement body)
{

    string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
    return Ok();

}
```